What is the difference between `ssid` and `ssid2` in hostapd config file?
In a hostapd configuration file, sometimes I see the key ssid to specify the SSID, and sometimes I see the key ssid2. What is the difference between these? I'm having trouble finding documentation about ssid2.

just a guess here, but some stacks are able to handle multiple SSIDs at once. Maybe it's really just the second?

From the config file (and you can see it in the source code as well):
##### IEEE 802.11 related configuration #######################################

# SSID to be used in IEEE 802.11 management frames
ssid=test
# Alternative formats for configuring SSID
# (double quoted string, hexdump, printf-escaped string)
#ssid2="test"
#ssid2=74657374
#ssid2=P"hello\nthere"

SSID accepts only ASCII, SSID2 accepts two other formats and allows to use quoting.
